# Sleep in tkinter (python2)

Tags: python, tkinter

I search to make a sleep in a while loop, in an tkinter's canvas. In Python2
The aim is to have a randomly moving point, refreshed every X seconds (then .I'll be able a bigger script to make what I want precisely), without any external user input.

For now, I made this :

```
import Tkinter, time

x1, y1, x2, y2 = 10, 10, 10, 10
def affichage():
    global x1, y1, x2, y2
    can1.create_rectangle(x1, y1, x2, y2, fill="blue", outline="blue")
def affichage2():
    global x1, y1, x2, y2
    can1.delete("all")
    can1.create_rectangle(x1, y1, x2, y2, fill="blue", outline="blue")

fen1 = Tkinter.Tk()
can1 = Tkinter.Canvas(fen1, height=200, width=200)
affichage()
can1.pack()
temps = 3000

while True:
    can1.after(temps, affichage2)
    x1 += 10
    y1 += 10
    x2 += 10
    y2 += 10
    temps += 1000
fen1.mainloop()

fen1.destroy()
```

(sorry for the french variable names :°)
So, I tried with the .after function, but I can't increase it how I want. I think it could be possible with multithreading, but there must be an easier solution.

Do you have any idea ?

Comment: `time.sleep(t)` where `t` is measured in seconds

Comment: `fen1.mainloop()` is the part when the application starts, if that never executes because it is below a `while True` with no `break` then the window would never show up at all.

Comment: others have pointed out the problem with `sleep`. There's also a problem with deleting and recreating the rectangle. The canvas has the ability to move an existing object; that will be more efficient than destroying and recreating the object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sleep` does not mix well with Tkinter because it makes the event loop halt, which in turn makes the window lock up and become unresponsive to user input. The usual way to make something happen every X seconds is to put the `after` call inside the very function you're passing to `after`. Try:

```
import Tkinter, time

x1, y1, x2, y2 = 10, 10, 10, 10
def affichage():
    global x1, y1, x2, y2
    can1.create_rectangle(x1, y1, x2, y2, fill="blue", outline="blue")
def affichage2():
    global x1, y1, x2, y2
    can1.delete("all")
    can1.create_rectangle(x1, y1, x2, y2, fill="blue", outline="blue")
    x1 += 10
    y1 += 10
    x2 += 10
    y2 += 10
    can1.after(1000, affichage2)

fen1 = Tkinter.Tk()
can1 = Tkinter.Canvas(fen1, height=200, width=200)
affichage()
can1.pack()
temps = 3000

can1.after(1000, affichage2)
fen1.mainloop()

fen1.destroy()
```