# It should create a label, display it and then delete it after 1 second but it doesn't create the label at all

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

So I am new to Python and I just don't know what I am doing wrong. It should create a canvas where you can enter your name, and according to your name the program will send a message. I want the message to dissappear after 1 second but the message doesn't appear at all.
Here is the code:

```
import tkinter as tk
import time

root = tk.Tk() 

canvas = tk.Canvas(root, height=700, width=800)
canvas.pack()

frame = tk.Frame(root, bg='grey')
frame.place(relwidth=0.8, relheight=0.8, relx=0.1, rely=0.1)

text = tk.Label(frame, height=6, text="Was ist dein Name? ", fg='black', bg='grey')
text.pack()

entry = tk.Entry(frame, bg='grey', fg='black', )
entry.pack()

ginga_gunga = tk.Label(frame, height=6, text=messaging, fg='black', bg='grey')
def taskcroissant():
    croissant = entry.get()
    if croissant == "Lukas" or croissant == "lukas":
        messaging = "Hello gay nigga"


    elif croissant == "elias" or croissant == "Elias":
        messaging = "Hi Fettsack"

    else:
        messaging = "Hi " + croissant
    ginga_gunga = tk.Label(frame, height=6, text=messaging, fg='black', bg='grey')
    ginga_gunga.pack()
    time.sleep(1)
    ginga_gunga.destroy()


button = tk.Button(frame, text="Enter", bg='#424949', command=taskcroissant)
button.pack()



root.mainloop()
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sleep in tkinter (python2)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38335168/sleep-in-tkinter-python2)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you need to do some operation on widgets after some time, try `parent_widget.after()` method.

This will do the given operation after some given time.

Here's Your Solution,

```
import tkinter as tk
import time

root = tk.Tk()

canvas = tk.Canvas(root, height=700, width=800)
canvas.pack()

frame = tk.Frame(root, bg='grey')
frame.place(relwidth=0.8, relheight=0.8, relx=0.1, rely=0.1)

text = tk.Label(frame, height=6, text="Was ist dein Name? ", fg='black', bg='grey')
text.pack()

entry = tk.Entry(frame, bg='grey', fg='black', )
entry.pack()

#ginga_gunga = tk.Label(frame, height=6, text="messaging", fg='black', bg='grey')
def taskcroissant():
    croissant = entry.get()
    if croissant == "Lukas" or croissant == "lukas":
        messaging = "Hello gay nigga"


    elif croissant == "elias" or croissant == "Elias":
        messaging = "Hi Fettsack"

    else:
        messaging = "Hi " + croissant
    ginga_gunga = tk.Label(frame, height=6, text=messaging, fg='black', bg='grey')
    ginga_gunga.pack()
    time.sleep(1)
    frame.after(1000,lambda:ginga_gunga.destroy())


button = tk.Button(frame, text="Enter", bg='#424949', command=taskcroissant)
button.pack()



root.mainloop()
```

In this program `frame.after(1000,lambda:ginga_gunga.destroy())` will do operation after 1000 miliseconds.The assigned `lambda` function will called after 1000 miliseconds.

For more details you can visit https://effbot.org/tkinterbook/widget.htm

Comment: The method is right but if you delete the time.sleep(1) the program functions better, sorry if I wasn't clear